# Researching family member that immigrated to USA from Poland in 1831

Tags: united-states, birth-records, surnames, poland

I'm looking for information on the surname Lyskowinski in Poland.  I know he came on a ship named Northumber that departed from London, England and arrived in America on Aug. 23, 1852.   His place of birth was Łódź, Poland on Dec 24, 1831.  I can't find any documents on the surname in Poland and don't know how or where to look.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Do you have a source for his immigration information that you can post as part of your question?  If so, there is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to add it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  The Illinois State Genealogical Society has a webinar coming up on Polish Immigration to America by Stephen Szabados on May 10 -- the live broadcast is free to the public.  Details here: http://www.ilgensoc.org/  If you can catch this presentation, it may give you background information that will help you.

Comment: Very likely it was Łyskowiński. A 'n' before "ski" is always wet, and the "Lys" letter combination is rare, while "Łys" is a common begining on the [List of common polish surnames](http://www.futrega.org/etc/nazwiska.html). I wouldn't be surprised if it was Łyszkowiński, it sounds more natural. As with all names in -ski, the feminine form is -ska, obviously.

Comment: Antoni Lyskowinski (Łyskowinski, son of Kacper and Katarzyna Chojnacka) and Antonina Julianna Hoftmajster (daughter of Jan i Balbina Krostoska) got married in 1842 in Uniejow by Lodz.

Answer (score 1):

Without the name of the parish or town from which your ancestor originated, it will be a tough slog and require enormous fortune to find more information. If you have patience and a lot of time, one place to look, though, is [metryki.genealodzy](http://metryki.genealodzy.pl/woj-LD) which is a Polish project for indexing parish records. It is hit or miss whether one's parish records are there. My experience has been mixed.